# android progress hud is automatically added

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I have added plugin for activityIndicator from cmd 
with following cmd line :

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-activityindicator
```

but with this added plugin i have an additional file added to the org.apache.cordova.plugin folder named as 'AndroidProgressHUD.java', 
this files includes lots of errors.
Please let me know how to resolve those errors and what for this file is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem, don't know how it happened but after restarting the Eclipse IDE the error was resolved. Hope this solution will also help for you.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, I resolved the errors after restarting the IDE, but want to know why this additional file was added.?